# Retrieving certain strings within a string using Oracle SQL - Part 2

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

Unfortunately I having a few issues now trying to get this going as my data has changed based on an original thread I started see:

[Retrieving certain strings within a string using Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110399/retrieving-certain-strings-within-a-string-using-oracle-sql)

My data has now changed to look like:

> member_of = CN=DAaXYZApple-Au, CN=DAaXYZApple-Readonly,
>   CN=aXYZApple-Write, CN=DAaXYZApple-Au-Admin, CN=aTest123_RW, {CN=#
>   XXY22,} CN=aInternet-1

Using the same type of techniques described in my original post,  I need to obtain all strings that hold the string "aXYZApple" only.
 So based on the above, the following results is what I am after and would be displayed only:

```
aXYZApple-Au
aXYZApple-Readonly
aXYZApple-Write
aXYZApple-Au-Admin
```

I am unsure if I still need to use Oracle regexp_substr as in my original post.

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue - no longer require assistance.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer?

Comment: As @Pedantic mentioned - please post the solution as an answer. You can aceept it later on

Comment: Apologies - pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my own question based on updated dataset is as follows, which is pretty much based on the solution provided to me in my original question, i.e.:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(line, 'aXYZApple[^,]*') subtxt
FROM (SELECT regexp_substr(:x, '[^,]*\,', 1, rownum + 1) line
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(:x) - length(REPLACE(:x, ',', '')))
WHERE line LIKE '%aXYZApple%';
```